# AttributeError with prediction using SVM model and scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, predict

I am using a trained SVM model to predict the class label for a new data sample. The data has been processed the exact same way as the training data (same features). I am getting an AttributeError when trying to predict:

```
data_to_predict = feature_row
prediction = trained_model.predict(data_to_predict)
```

The data_to_predict is a pandas DataFrame with a single row. I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'probA_'
```

I believe (perhaps wrongly) that the issue is in the shape of the data, since `feature_row` looks correct when I print it. Here is what I tried so far:

1. made sure the model was trained with `probability=True`
2. tried reshaping the data as `[feature_row]`, error changed to `KeyError: 0`
3. tried changing the data into an array `np.array(feature_row)`, that returned the original error
4. tried reshaping the array `np.array(feature_row).reshape((-1, 1))`, error is `ValueError: Number of features of the input must be equal to or greater than that of the fitted transformer. Transformer n_features is 31 and input n_features is 1.`
5. tried reshaping the opposite way `np.array(feature_row).reshape((1, -1))`, back to original error
6. finally, tried `[np.array(feature_row).reshape(-1, 1)]`, got `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`

**Extra Info:** I'm not sure if it makes any difference in resolving this issue, but the model involves:

- ColumnTransformer with a TfidfVectorizer on one column (with `remainder='passthrough'`)
- Followed by the SVC step `SVC(probability=True, class_weight='balanced')`
- scikit-learn version 0.22.1

Edit: In case someone comes across this thread later. With help from
Victor Luu, we managed to isolate the problem to the pickle file itself. After some further probing, I discovered that I was training and testing the model in two different environments that had slightly different scikit-learn versions (0.23.1 and 0.22.1), once I made sure these matched, the error disappeared.

Comment: Hi, have you fitted the model yet? If not yet, need to fit it first

Comment: I have fit it, it's been trained already and I'm loading it from a pickle file

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, loading from a pickle file can cause problems like this. My suggestion is to predict right after you have trained the model, do not use the saved model.

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately, it's part of an ML pipeline and the trained model needs to be stored on the server and called to predict regularly

Comment: I mean you try that first to see if it works. Then you can be sure that the problem is due to using the model from pickle file, and can continue to find solution from there. Also, check if you saved the model correctly, see [model persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)

Comment: I can try that, sure, it will take time to retrain the model, so I will return to this thread once i have done this.

Comment: also, based on model persistence in sklearn, it is better to use `joblib` then `pickle` to dump model, you should try `joblib`.

Comment: Not very relevant, but FYI SVC do not have predict_proba(). Also, just retrain the model on a small sample first, then call predict to see if the bug is fixed, that way it is much faster.

Comment: I understand that about SVC, which is why I use it with probability=True, which gives probability estimates using Platt scaling. It's good enough for my purposes. I just tried a smaller version of the training and tried to predict using the same script, there are no issues there. The problem seems to be indeed the pickle file